# App.config changed somehow and broke my project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

Despite making no real changes my project just stopped working. I traced it to the following, but I didn't make this change, and to be honest throughout my build using TFS nuget consistently seems to bugger things up, so it might be that?

anyway, App.config used to simply be this:

```
  <appSettings configSource="appsettings.config">
  </appSettings>
```

And tonight it got changed to:

```
<appSettings configSource="appsettings.config">
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  </appSettings>
```

And then added all this was added to the file:

```
<system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
```

Answer (score 1):

This just happened to me.  It appears to have been caused by simply navigating to the "Services" section in the project properties, even though I didn't make any changes in that section.

More details on  [Visual Studio automatically reenable “client application services”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315631/why-does-visual-studio-automatically-reenable-client-application-services)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing and it broke my login code; I just kept getting errors every time I used the membership methods.  I hadn't changed anything and fiddled around for an hour or two before comparing my app.config with a backed up version.  I replaced the part that had been changed and it all started working again.

I had been using ClickOnce to publish the project when it happened.