# ConnectionManager.AppSettings

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I stumbled across an SQL insertion in C# and I am trying to figure the ConnectionManager.Appsetting. Can anyone help me understand the significance of the following code:-

```
 strSQL = "INSERT INTO [History]"
                + " (xxxx, yyyy, zzzz)"
                + " values (@xxxx, @yyyy, @RoleKey)";
            Connection.Open();
            command = new SqlCommand(strSQL, Connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xxxx", xx);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yyyy", "1");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoleKey", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RoleKey"].ToString());
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Connection.Close();
```

Now when I look at the table, instinctively I want the value of RoleKey to be table driven from another table that maintains the values of RoleKey with individual description fields for each value.

I am trying to understand what the statement:-

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoleKey", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RoleKey"].ToString());
```

is trying to do? I tried to run this insertion via C# and there is a null exception error on this line.

I have been referring to MSDN thus far:-http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

In app.config I see:-

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  </appSettings>
```

Can anyone give me some further info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ConfigurationManager.AppSettings comes from either the web config in an ASP.Net application, or the App.config in a regular application.

Look for something like this:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="RoleKey" value="MyRoleKeyValue" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

That way you can change rolekey without having to recompile the code.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my code, basically I don't see any value being added, which would explain the error.

Comment: You'll need to add that value then... we can't really help tell you what that value should be though, but the fact that it's missing is why you're getting that error.

Comment: yes, agreed. thanks for pointing me to the right direction. appreciate it. :)

Comment: although a bit confused why ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri is being used. thats kind of weird.

Comment: interesting, some googling led to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963270/purpose-of-clientsettingsprovider-serviceuri-in-app-config